# Como criar um log em html com log4net

Tags: c#, html, .net, log4net

Tenho um projeto que já utiliza o log4net, porém gostaria de mostrar esse log em HTML. Procurei em vários sites e ninguém implementou essa solução.

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de projeto?

Comment: É um Webservice Framework 3.5 C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que tu consegue salvar o log como `XML` e que `HTML` também é uma linguagem de marcação, tu pode tentar se aproveitar disso.

Você pode reescrever a classe [XmlLayoutBase](https://github.com/babaru/log4net/blob/master/src/Layout/XMLLayoutBase.cs), como foi feito pelo [*Darin*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147774/3257568):

```
public class MeuHtmlLayout : XmlLayoutBase
{
    protected override void FormatXml(XmlWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("div");
        writer.WriteStartElement("p");
        writer.WriteString(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

No seu **app.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="log.html" /> <!-- nunca testei com .html, qualquer coisa volta .txt -->
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="SeuNamespace.MeuHtmlLayout" />
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Para **testar**:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
        log.Debug("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

É para produzir uma **saída** do tipo:

```
<div><p>Hello world</p></div>
```